# very simple script fails on onChange event. Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, getelementbyid, typeerror

I know this might look like an already asked question, and it probably is. But I've checked all of the answers already given and none of them fits my problem.

So here is the thing.

I have a **very simple** piece of code, like **super simple**. But I can't get my script to work. I always get the error *Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyId is not a function*.

Obviously the code below is just a practice / testing code, I know it's completely worthless. Still I can't seem to make it work.

Things I've already tried to move the script to the body but nothing changes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SUPPORTO FUNZIONALE BI</title>

<script>

    function selectValues(){

    var ruolo = document.getElementbyId("select_ruolo").innerHTML;
    console.log(ruolo);

}

</script>



</head>

<body>



<h1>SUPPORTO FUNZIONALE BI</h1>

<div id= 'main_nav'> <!-- INIZIO MAIN_NAV  -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="SF.html">HOME</a></li>
    <!--    <li><a href ="">SERVIZI ATTIVI / DA ATTIVARE</a></li> -->
        <li><a href ="">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="service_management.html">SERVICE MANAGEMENT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> <!--  FINE MAIN_NAV-->   

<div id= 'content'><!-- INIZIO_CONTENT -->
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend> User information </legend>
                Nome: <input type="text" label="nome utente">
                Cognome: <input type="text" label="cognome"> 
                Ruolo: <select id= "select_ruolo" onchange="selectValues();">
                            <option>-</option>
                            <option>ISF</option>
                            <option>DM</option>
                            <option>RCM</option>
                            <option>RPM</option>
                            <option>Head of Franchise</option>
                        </select>
                Linea/Franchise: <select id ="select_linea">
                            <option> </option>
                                </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

 <div> <!-- FINE CONTENT -->

</body>

</html>
```

Can anyone help me identify where the problem lies ?

Comment: That's because `document.getElementbyId` is not a function. The language is not lying to you. You didn't find some unknown edge case. You might however try looking the function up and spelling it correctly. `document.getElementById`

Comment: thanks, you are right! couldn't see that. I was sure I had checked the spelling, but obviously I did not check it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo. The function is

```
document.getElementById("element")
```

The B is capitalized. It's working for me with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>SUPPORTO FUNZIONALE BI</title>

<script>

    function selectValues(){

    var ruolo = document.getElementById("select_ruolo").innerHTML;
    console.log(ruolo);

}

</script>



</head>

<body>



<h1>SUPPORTO FUNZIONALE BI</h1>

<div id= 'main_nav'> <!-- INIZIO MAIN_NAV  -->
    <ul>
        <li><a href="SF.html">HOME</a></li>
    <!--    <li><a href ="">SERVIZI ATTIVI / DA ATTIVARE</a></li> -->
        <li><a href ="">FAQs</a></li>
        <li><a href="service_management.html">SERVICE MANAGEMENT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> <!--  FINE MAIN_NAV-->   

<div id= 'content'><!-- INIZIO_CONTENT -->
    <form>
        <fieldset>
            <legend> User information </legend>
                Nome: <input type="text" label="nome utente">
                Cognome: <input type="text" label="cognome"> 
                Ruolo: <select id= "select_ruolo" onchange="selectValues();">
                            <option>-</option>
                            <option>ISF</option>
                            <option>DM</option>
                            <option>RCM</option>
                            <option>RPM</option>
                            <option>Head of Franchise</option>
                        </select>
                Linea/Franchise: <select id ="select_linea">
                            <option> </option>
                                </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

 <div> <!-- FINE CONTENT -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I was sure it was something idiotic! Four eyes are always better then one. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, I do it all the time! If this answers all of your question please accept it (green check mark) so that SO recognizes the question as answered.